# Chromecast reboots after trying to play a movie from DS Video

Tags: android, video, chromecast, synology

I have a Synology DS212j and a Chromecast in my wifi network. I use them to reproduce movies I have on my Synology directly to the Chromecast by using Synology's Android app DS VIDEO

the system has ever worked very well, but since a couple of weeks everytime i start playing a movie, Chromecast loads the video, plays a couple of seconds and suddenly stops and reboots itself

Synology DSM version: DSM 5.1-5022 Update 2

Chromecast firmware version: 26653

Movies files: .mkv H264 AAC

could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my DS Video app I changed the Playback Quality from high to low and the problem stopped.

Once I set up port forwarding I found that I could set it to Auto.

Comment: where I can find the option to change the playback quality? I can't find it in the application settings